# htaccess - will not recognize url pattern

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tested the following pattern in online testers and everyone of them the has it working fine. In addition the rules are working for other similar iterations no problem.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !404 [NC]
RewriteRule ^manager/services/([\w\-]+) manager/services/controller.php?PAGE=$1 [QSA,L,R=302]
```

For the REQUEST URI (cant give the URL atm as its still insecure):

```
/manager/services/get-items
```

But this rule is throwing a 404 error. controller most definitely exists and I can visit it manually with no problem..

The only other possibility I Can think of is some kind of interaction with the directory level htaccess which only as allow,deny for my ip address setup but no redirects.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with all those conditions?

Comment: Ignoring the other directories. They arent really necessary but I put together a bit of a frankenstein trying to find the solution.

Comment: All you want is the last rule to work?

Comment: Yep! I removed the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the htaccess in the root and give this a try.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^manager/services/([^/]+)/? /manager/services/controller.php?PAGE=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm assuming you have htaccess enabled since you said you had other stuff in there but make sure it's set to `AllowOverride All` in Apache config.

Edit:

Or you can try and add the code to the manager folder htaccess file with this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /manager/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^services/([^/]+)/? services/controller.php?PAGE=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Crud. Still going to a 404. Im going to submit a ticket. Thanks for your help though, this should work.

Comment: Also I always forget to use the -f -d conditions so if nothing else I get to take that away :)

Comment: Also just make sure to clear your cache or try in a new browser to make sure previous rules aren't cached. Also Is this a CMS? Are you getting a 404 from Apache or from your script?

Comment: Also where is your htaccess file at?

Comment: It is a cms but one I built so it should have any interruptions. The 404 is definitely from Apache. What is odd is that the directive above it works perfectly fine for the 'manager' folder. This is on a remote hosting server, I dont even know if its shared or dedicated, probably a VPS.

Comment: I did try to find a way to alter the http.conf file but they dont have (easy) access to it. At thsi point im wondering if the naming of the directories has some whacky thing to with this failure

Comment: This htaccess is in the root directory. There IS a second one in the manager folder, but it only has an order allow,deny directive

Comment: And there is nothing else in there but order allow.. etc?

Comment: Nope nothing else. I am going to disable it for a second and see if that changes anythnig.

Comment: -_- i deleted the manager folder htaccess and now Im getting lots of 403...Im pretty sure something is bad server side. This would definitely not be the first time.

Comment: Hmm.. yeah something is screwy.. What does you apache error_log say is the reason for the 403. That will give a big clue.

Comment: Stale file handle. Hmm do you know anything about htaccess cacheing? Thats what the error sounds like to me.

Comment: that really doesn't sound like it has anything to do with the problem. Look at your `access_log`. That is where the 403 error will be. And what does that say?

Comment: This is strange im showing an error: [Thu Mar 05 21:37:51 2015] [9495552] [negotiation:error] [client 71.XXX.XXX.XXX:54258] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/chroot/home/content/52/9495552/html/manager/services/get-items (None could be negotiated).

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2218-negotiation-discovered-file-s-matching-request-none-could-be-negotiated.htm

Comment: LOL I was going to tell you Try turning off multiviews.

Comment: See my edit in the first part of the answer. See if that works.

Comment: HAHAHA YES THIS FIXED IT. I seriously just needed to flip this one switch and a 10 hour project just started working. 1000 Thanksyous

Comment: Sweet, glad I could help you track it down.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity I had a directory named 'services' in the web root on a GoDaddy server. Something is mucking it up and causing a mix of 404 and 500 errors for anything related to that folder.

Renaming the folder to web_services resolved the issue.